# Coding an Array of Maps in Java

Tags: java, arrays, hashmap

I am struggling to code an array of maps in Java.
The pseudo-code below demonstrates what I am trying to do.

```
Dim maparray(mapnumber) As Map
Maparray(0) = Map1
Maparray(1) = Map2
```

and so on.
How would I do this in Java?  I know the array size, so having a dynamic array is not necessary.
My current java code is here:

```
JSONArray activityjson = new JSONArray(jsonObject.getString("activity"));
Map<String, String> activity = new HashMap<String, String>();

for (int i = 0; i < activityjson.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject obj = (JSONObject) activityjson.get(i);

    activity.put("ID", obj.get("ActivityID").toString());
    activity.put("Name", obj.get("ActivityName").toString());
    activity.put("Desc", obj.get("ActivityDesc").toString());
    activity.put("Req", obj.get("ActivityReq").toString());
    activity.put("Start", obj.get("StartDate").toString());
    activity.put("End", obj.get("EndDate").toString());
    activity.put("Location", obj.get("Location").toString());
    activity.put("Points", obj.get("AwardPoints").toString());

}
```

At the end of the inside of the for loop, I want to add the current state of activity to the maparray[i].
Thanks *8)*

Comment: You would be better off creating a class that has all of those keys as properties, you're getting yourself into a mess of a headache going about it the way that you are...

Comment: I'd start by creating an actual array of HashMap in your code... Or, really, I'd not use Hashmap at all, and actually deserialize the JSON array into a list of Java objects using Gson or Jackson

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is best done using a list instead of an array.

```
JSONArray activityjson = new JSONArray(jsonObject.getString("activity"));
  List<Map<String, String>> data = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();
  for (int i = 0; i < activityjson.length(); i++) {
    Map<String, String> activity = new HashMap<String, String>();
                            JSONObject obj = (JSONObject) activityjson.get(i);

                            activity.put("ID", obj.get("ActivityID").toString());
                            activity.put("Name", obj.get("ActivityName").toString());
                            activity.put("Desc", obj.get("ActivityDesc").toString());
                            activity.put("Req", obj.get("ActivityReq").toString());
                            activity.put("Start", obj.get("StartDate").toString());
                            activity.put("End", obj.get("EndDate").toString());
                            activity.put("Location", obj.get("Location").toString());
                            activity.put("Points", obj.get("AwardPoints").toString());
                            data.add(activity);
                        }
// now access activity.get(0), activity.get(1), ...
```

Comment: I used `data.get(1).get("ID").toString()` to retrieve the data from the list.  Works exactly as I wanted.  Thanks!